# Turn RSA public and private keys into strings in R

Tags: r, encryption, openssl, cryptography

Let´s assume that I create a private key in R as such:

```
 key <- openssl::rsa_keygen()
```

This will create an object with two classes:

```
class(key)
```

> [1] "key" "rsa"

I can see my public key, but only in terminal. If I try to get a character string from it, I fail:

```
key
```

> [2048-bit rsa private key] md5: 7df8a65296e753a5a49a9037860ccb0f

```
as.character(key)
```

> [1] "30" "82" "04" "a3" "02" "01" "00" "02" "82" "01" "01" "00" "d3"
> "2c" "3c" "1d" "1f" "de" "32" "72" "44" "a3" "7e" "74" "a4"
> "e2" ...

Is there a way to extract character strings from RSA pubkey and private keys? If yes, is it possible to recreate the `key` object from pubkey and private keys strings?

### More details as suggested by @MrFlick and including @akrun solution.

Assuming the following strings as `pub.key` and `private.key`.

```
private.key <- digest::digest(as.character(key))
pub.key <- sub(".*:\\s+", "", capture.output(key)[2])
private.key
```

> [1] "78761f4f60998970bb687aa2fde96aec"

```
pub.key
```

> [1] "7df8a65296e753a5a49a9037860ccb0f"

Can I recreate the `key` object with those strings as the below pseudocode?

```
key.recreated <- recreateKey(private.key, pub.key)
class(key.recreated)
```

> [1] "key" "rsa"

```
key.recreated==key
```

> TRUE

Comment: So what value do you need in a string exactly? Are you trying to get the "7df8a65296e753a5a49a9037860ccb0f" in this example? How do you want the key formatted?

Comment: I am assuming that pub.key and private key are, in essence, two strings of letters and numbers. If that is true, I would like to see both values as character strings. @akrun is half way. If private key is not a string, then private key string is just a misconception from me.

Comment: Well the values are really bytes. There are different ways to encode those into letters and numbers. It’s unclear what kind of encoding you want to use. Do you have some example you are trying to match? The as.character values are the hex values of the bytes in your key.

Comment: @MrFlick, now I see. Well, in that case one question remains from my original inquiry. Is it possible to (re)create an object similar to `key` from two strings (i.e. pub.key and private.key)?

Comment: Well again, what do those strings look like? As long as you know how to parse the bytes correctly you should be able to turn to into a key. It’s very hard to give specifics without some sort of reproducible example.

Comment: It's still pretty unclear what exactly you need. The `openssl` package has many function to for reading/writing keys to different formats. The value you see printed "7df8...." is only the fingerprint of the key, not the key itself. See the `?read_pem` and `?write_pem` help files for better ways to encode they key into a string. Maybe this vignette will help: `vignette("keys","openssl")`

Answer (score 1):

We could use `capture.output`, extract the second element, remove the substring till the spaces to return the key

```
sub(".*:\\s+", "", capture.output(key)[2])
```

Also, for accessing the `pubkey`

```
key$pubkey$ssh
```